# How can I do for recording Audio from sound-card using java?

Tags: java, audio, javax.sound.sampled

I want to record audio from sound-card using java. so this is what i got. but it only creats 0 sec wav file. recording didn't work with this code.

How can I do for recording Audio from sound-card?  Please help TT

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;

public class SimpleAudioRecorder extends Thread

{
    private TargetDataLine m_line;
    private AudioFileFormat.Type m_targetType;
    private AudioInputStream m_audioInputStream;
    private File m_outputFile;

    public SimpleAudioRecorder(TargetDataLine line,
            AudioFileFormat.Type targetType, File file) {
        m_line = line;
        m_audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(line);
        m_targetType = targetType;
        m_outputFile = file;
    }

    public void start() {
        m_line.start();
        super.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        m_line.stop();
        m_line.close();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            AudioSystem.write(m_audioInputStream, m_targetType, m_outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String strFilename = "D://wave.wav";
        File outputFile = new File(strFilename);

        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F,
                false);

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,
                audioFormat);
        TargetDataLine targetDataLine = null;
        try {
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            out("unable to get a recording line");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        AudioFileFormat.Type targetType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

        SimpleAudioRecorder recorder = new SimpleAudioRecorder(targetDataLine,
                targetType, outputFile);

        out("Press ENTER to start the recording.");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recorder.start();
        out("Recording...");

        out("Press ENTER to stop the recording.");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recorder.stopRecording();
        out("Recording stopped.");
    }

    private static void printUsageAndExit() {
        out("SimpleAudioRecorder: usage:");
        out("\tjava SimpleAudioRecorder -h");
        out("\tjava SimpleAudioRecorder <audiofile>");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void out(String strMessage) {
        System.out.println(strMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a *sound card* these days?  Perhaps *audio input* would be a better terminology to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think TargetDataLine method does not have `start()` method it uses `read()` method instead.